# Can I customize the iPad 2 HDMI output or has it just a mirror function?

Tags: ios, ipad, screen

Can someone tell me if I can customize the HDMI output of the iPad2? I mean that the view on the big screen is not just a mirror of the iPad view.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends on the app that you are using.

Apps can choose to present different content on the external display if they want. For example Keynote can display the slides on the external display and the presenters notes on the built-in display.

Comment: Well, this was a actually a programmers question and should not be in here. Maybe I did't made that clear enough, but I posted it on Stack Overflow and it was moved here for some reason. I know that Keynote can show a different view on the external device, but it's from Apple an they might have other permissions for that. The question is, can I do this with my App too and present the user a different UIView on the external screen ...

Comment: @Tim That isn't specified in your question at all. Please repost this to Stack Overflow with that information in the question. Thanks.